Angular lazy loading module routes not rendering
Essentially I am trying to load a module called shop, this shop module has it's own set of routes. When I navigate to localhost:4200/shop nothing renders and no console errors. If i route directly to landing when it's in app.routes.ts, it render perfect but lazyloading the children doesn't work.
app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'shop',
    loadChildren: () => import('./shop/shop.module').then((m) => m.ShopModule),
  },
];

shop.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ShopRoutingModule } from './shop-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ShopRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class ShopModule { }

shop-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./shop.module').then((m) => m.ShopModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ShopRoutingModule {}


The code you provided looks fine, so if something is missed it is somewhere else. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

@Shlang I figured it out. I was lazy loading the shops module then lazy loading the shops module.. inside the shops module
